# JavaScript não funciona no Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

Meu código está funcionando no Chrome, mas no Safari ele não passa por nenhum `if else` e vai direto pra o `else`.

```
//FUNÇÃO PARA ATIVAR NA SELEÇÃO DOS DROPBOX
var selecao= document.querySelectorAll('.validation-lenient'); 
function handleClick (event)
{

//IDENTIFICAÇÃO DO CAMPO SOMA PELO ID DO FORMULARIO HTML
var soma = document.getElementById('campo-soma').innerText;

//PREENCIMENTO DO CAMPO SOMA
var camposoma = document.querySelector('[name="field46[]"]').value = soma;

//VARIAVEL IF PARA PREÇO COM BASE NAS SOMAS DOS PESOS ANTERIORES
if (camposoma == "2 2 50 Almoço") {
      nomefesta = "Festa VIP";
      nomefesta2 = "Festa TOP";
      tabelaprazo = "TABELA | PRAZO(10%) | AVISTA (15%)";
      precoVip = " valor | valor | valor";
      precoTop = " valor | valor | valor";
  }
else if (camposoma == "2 2 60 Almoço") {
      nomefesta = "Festa VIP";
      nomefesta2 = "Festa TOP";
      tabelaprazo = "TABELA | PRAZO(10%) | AVISTA (15%)";
      precoVip = " valor | valor | valor";
      precoTop = " valor | valor | valor";
  }
else {
    precoVip = "não se aplica";
    precoTop = "não se aplica";
}

//PREENCIMENTO DO CAMPO ORÇAMENTO
var campoorcamento = document.querySelector('[name="field51[]"]').value = precoVip;
var campoorcamento = document.querySelector('[name="field52[]"]').value = precoTop;
var campoorcamento = document.querySelector('[name="field58[]"]').value = nomefesta;
var campoorcamento = document.querySelector('[name="field63[]"]').value = nomefesta2;

}
//FIM DA FUNÇÃO DOS DOS DROPBOX
selecao.forEach(function(item){
item.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {once: false});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não deveria estar funcionando nem no Chrome (ou qualquer outro navegador), porque você está comparando um elemento a uma string, veja:

```
if (camposoma == "2 2 50 Almoço") {
```

A variável `camposoma` foi declarada anteriormente como um objeto:

```
var camposoma = document.querySelector('[name="field46[]"]').value = soma;
```

Veja que essa variável referencia o elemento `document.querySelector('[name="field46[]"]')`, não ao seu valor, embora esteja fazendo duas coisas ao mesmo tempo: declarando a variável e alterando o valor do elemento.

> Outro possível problema de compatibilidade é no uso do `.innerText`.
>   Troque por `.textContent`. Talvez seja necessário também usar o `.trim()` para remover possíveis espaços antes e depois da string. Ficaria:

```
var soma = document.getElementById('campo-soma').textContent.trim();
```

Em relação aos if's, coloque `.value` após `camposoma` para retornar o valor do elemento:

```
if (camposoma.value == "2 2 50 Almoço") {
      nomefesta = "Festa VIP";
      nomefesta2 = "Festa TOP";
      tabelaprazo = "TABELA | PRAZO(10%) | AVISTA (15%)";
      precoVip = " valor | valor | valor";
      precoTop = " valor | valor | valor";
  }
else if (camposoma.value == "2 2 60 Almoço") {
      nomefesta = "Festa VIP";
      nomefesta2 = "Festa TOP";
      tabelaprazo = "TABELA | PRAZO(10%) | AVISTA (15%)";
      precoVip = " valor | valor | valor";
      precoTop = " valor | valor | valor";
  }
else {
    precoVip = "não se aplica";
    precoTop = "não se aplica";
}
```

Comment: Eu acredito que esse não seja o problema, afinal, ele define o valor de `soma` por `document.getElementById('campo-soma').innerText`, no entanto, eu acho que o problema seja ao obter o valor com `innerText`, [há um post com esse mesmo problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078122/safari-bug-with-elements-innertext).

Comment: O problema é na variável `camposoma`, e não na variável `soma`.

Comment: Sim, mas ela é atribuida com `var camposoma = document.querySelector('[name="field46[]"]').value = soma;`, primeiro ele atribui o valor da variável `soma` ao elemento que ele acabou de buscar pelo `querySelector`, e após isso, atribui na variável `camposoma`, no fim, o valor de `camposoma` é igual ao do `soma`.

Comment: Entendi, mas não vi nada de anormal nisso não. O único problema que percebi no código foi o que descrevi na resposta.

Comment: Ah tah. Realmente o innerText pode não ser compatível com o Safari. Vou adicionar na resposta. Valeu!